# Titanium 3.2.2GA drawer module error

Tags: ios, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

We have Titanium 3.2.2 GA SDK which is being used for our titanium (iOS) project. I downloaded and installed the dk.napp.drawer 1.1.5 iOS platform module. However, it gives an error "Found incompatible modules". Where can I find and install the older version of dk.napp.drawer which is compatible with Ti 3.2.2 GA or is there another way to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Does this have what you need?

https://github.com/viezel/NappDrawer/releases

Comment: If you look at this link: http://gitt.io/component/dk.napp.drawer , all the versions say that they require Ti 3.2.3GA

Comment: The source is there, perhaps you can compile it to the version of the SDK you want it to be compatible with.  Not sure what that requires you to do, perhaps just change a config file that says it works with the SDK you want since they are so close.